# Can't import pandas although Its installed (module not found) MBP

Tags: python, pandas, module

Hi Guys I've been searching for more than two hours by now. I searched all over SOF and Youtube but found no answer.

I Have anaconda installed and as they said on the installing instructions pandas and other diferente pakgs are included already, but when I try to `import pandas as pd` on *Jupyer or VS* I get the **module not found error**.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'*
```

I only have `python 3.8` installed no other versions. And I've confirmed several times that pandas is installed.

**SHOW PANDAS AT TERMINAL**

```
(base) Rogers-MBP:~ rogerrendon$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.0.5
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /Users/rogerrendon/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, numpy, pytz
Required-by: statsmodels, seaborn
```

**PYTHON VERSION**

```
(base) Rogers-MBP:~ rogerrendon$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

**PIP3 INSTALL CHECK**

```
pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

Can please somebody help me? I'm loosing my mind hahah

Comment: "I only have python 3.8 installed no other versions." this is probably false on a MacBook. OSX comes with python, so if you've installed anaconda, you have two installations. This is probably a result of that

Comment: It sounds to me like *Jupyter* and *VS* may be using your system python distribution rather than anaconda (which pip seems to be using). You can get the path to the python executable currently in use with `import sys; print('sys.executable')`, and you can get a list of folders where python searches for libraries with `import sys; print('sys.path')`. This should tell you where this other installation resides.

Comment: Hi Aron! So I ran this codes on the VS and got this with 'sys.executable':
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/rogerrendon/opt/anaconda3/DataScience/livecode-prework.py and for 'sys.path' and got this: ->

Comment: $/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/rogerrendon/opt/anaconda3/DataScience/livecode-prework.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
['/Users/rogerrendon/opt/anaconda3/DataScience', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/rogerrendon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packag

Comment: this definitely confirms that VS is using the built-in python distribution from apple, and not using anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the built-in python from apple instead of Anaconda. During installation there is supposed to be a prompt that asks you something to the effect of "do you want anaconda to be your default python installation". If this didn't come up or you clicked past it too fast, it will not have made any changes to your bash profile (zsh on catalina) that would make your system aware of the new python installation. Some things (like pip) may use other ways to discover the correct distribution to target which is why that seems to find anaconda just fine.

If you open up your user folder and make hidden files visible (cmd shift period), you should find either bash or zsh profile files that control the startup of any system shell you call. If you don't find somewhere in those files a block put in there by the installer (it should be very clear from the comments), then effectively anaconda was installed, but never activated. Try opening a command prompt and calling:

`(base) Rogers-MBP:~ rogerrendon$ source /Users/rogerrendon/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`

then if you are running 10.14 or earlier:

`(base) Rogers-MBP:~ rogerrendon$ conda init`

or if you have Catalina (10.15)

`(base) Rogers-MBP:~ rogerrendon$ conda init zsh`

Comment: I also found a [good article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-successfully-install-anaconda-on-a-mac-and-actually-get-it-to-work-53ce18025f97) discussing in more depth problems like this, and how to solve them (with anaconda).

Comment: First of all thank you agian Aron! Second of all seesh... I'm starting to hate apple even more hahaha. Third I'll be trying this, I've allready tried those commands but  got no success. I'm now reading Anne Bonner articles! Ty again!

Comment: Finally! I uninstalled anaconda and then installed  again this time via Terminal. And then navigated through the files at the user folder and double clicked the **anaconda3/bin/activate** file, closed Anaconda and opened a new Jupyter notebook and... Pandas was indeed working! Thank you so much Aaron!

Comment: @rogerrendon I'm glad you were able to figure it out. This isn't a problem unique to Apple though. What is happening behind the scenes is that Anaconda is using virtual environments to manage switching to its own installation of python. If you develop several projects that have different conflicting requirements as far as python version or even just the version of a library, virtual environments are very useful. Generally the idea is it changes where your system searches for programs temporarily rather than permanently, so it's easy to switch back and forth.

Comment: @rogerrendon I don't personally have the need for environments often, so I typically skip this whole mechanism, and add the anaconda folders directly to my $PATH variable by editing \etc\path: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/ It's a bit more of a brute force solution, which makes it harder to change back later (though not that hard..)

Comment: Hmm got it! Indeed I'm new to python and data science and for now I don't need to change between environments, Ryans solutions seems like a nice solution also but for now I think im sticking with the solution I have, it's working so i guess I'll wait for the necessity for change. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with similar issues in the past. The first thing to check is to make sure that you don't have multiple python versions installed throughout your computer (unless you require this). If you properly installed anaconda then you should have python within that environment. To uninstall other pythons, go to your uninstall apps page and find the python versions if they exist and remove them.

If after doing this an issue still arises, restart and check your path. Make sure you have paths to ...\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin, ...\anaconda3\Library\bin, and ...\anaconda3\Scripts

Another thing to try is conda installing pandas although anaconda should include this package already.

I've found an issue using hydrogen within Atom (basically allows jupyter to be used in Atom) where the atom search paths set from install are to the wrong package locations. Fixing this could become cumbersome so I would recommend the nuclear option of uninstalling everything and reinstalling if nothing above works.

Comment: It can be a very bad idea to try to replace the built-in python distribution within Linux or MacOS as the operating system depends on it. You should only ever uninstall a python distribution you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Setting->Project Interpreter->click on plus sign->type 'pandas'->Install Package.